# How to fix problem with users Identity in Asp MVC .Net Application? Sometimes user is wrongly recognized as another one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, active-directory, iis-7.5, user-identification

I have a problem with Asp Net MVC4 web application. I am using Windows Authentication and IIS7. User is authenticated based on Active Directory and from time to time (like in 1-3% of all users attempts to the website) user is recognized as someone else who at the same time also entered the website (I checked it in IIS logs).
There is about 10 places in the code where I need to get user current name and I get this data using this:
    `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

I have already tried to cache username at the very beginning, when user enter the website and then use this cached username instead of accessing it via HttpContext. And surprisingly issue was occurring even more often.

I also tried to change settings in IIS like described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/360083/iis-7-windows-authentication-wrong-user

But issue still occurred.

Please let me know what else could I try? This issue really haunts me :)
Thank you in advance for the answer!

Comment: If caching the username made it worse, then the problem is likely how you are caching. Can you show the code you are using to cache stuff (even if you aren't caching the username anymore, you must be caching something else)

Comment: Ok, but still, even if this caching work it will only make this issue occur less often. Let's say I will cache the user once he enters the website and he gets recognized incorrectly. Then the wrong username will be used each time in later use of the application by this user.

Comment: I'm not saying you *should* cache the username - I don't think you should. But I am saying that you must be caching *something*. Are you caching any user data?